# Open File Button - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a problem where I cannot link my open Button to the "open" command, help please!

```
Error= fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
NameError: global name 'tkFileDialog' is not defined
```

What I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename

frm = Frame(parent)
frm.pack(fill=X)
Button(frm, text=' Browse  ',   command=self.getFileName).pack(side=LEFT)

def getFileName(self):
    fileName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    iconEntry.insert(0, fileName)

SimpleEditor().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

rather than

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
```

you probably just want

```
import tkFileDialog
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah. Since you are already doing "tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()", you don't need to do this "from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename"

Simply, import tkFileDialog will do.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using`from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename`

use`import Tkinter.Filedialog as tkFiledialog`